# getting error when i run my the project in springfrmework

Tags: spring, jdbc

here is the error:

> org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO organization
>   (company_name, year_of_cop, postal_code, employee_count,
>   slogan)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, )]; Parameter index out of range (5 > number
>   of parameters, which is 4).; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (5 > number of
>   parameters, which is 4).

here is my method:

```
public boolean create(Organization org) {
        String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO organization (company_name, year_of_cop, postal_code, employee_count, slogan)"+
             "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, )";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the last parameter placeholder in the query string:

```
public boolean create(Organization org) { 
    String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO organization (company_name, year_of_cop, postal_code, employee_count, slogan)"+ "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    ...
}
```